# Margin top issue with safari in css

Tags: safari, css-float, margin

I'm having a problem, when i check the site on any other browser such as IE, Firefox or Chrome,it works perfectly but on Safari i'm having a problem with the top margin. I have 2 pages which are similar, the page life on board is doing fine on any browser but the page blue cruise has an issue with Safari, the text are down and should not be that way. How can i position the margin to have the text on top and same as the page life on board?
Any help please?

here is the ulr http://www.guletsturkey.co.uk/blue-cruise.html

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have a set width on this CSS rule that is site wide and the  the problem seems to be the fixed width you have set that conflicts with your iFrame effecting this page. This style sheet seems to be a global style sheet across your website so on the blue cruise page ONLY i would write this rule.

```
#Gulets_flash {
 margin-left: 178px;
 width: auto;/*THIS IS PART OF THE PROBLEM*/
 height: 600px;
}
```

Also  I am not sure what your client wants or the design you are going for but I would recommend using a container to wrap your content and than using floats to position so of your content.